# How to run process behalf of another parent process in bash OS X?

Tags: objective-c, c, bash, macos

I've developed two processes (A and B) where from process A I launch process B.
The problem is that process B is getting launched in behalf of the 1st launched process as parent.
I need to run it in a way where parent process should be A (NOT launched).
Here is the code of how I run it programmatically:

```
system("open -a 'B.app'");
```

Comment: This `A` is an actual process, & not some `source`d script, right ?

Comment: if you use `open` then you're explicitly asking launch services to start the program. If you want to launch it with your program as the parent then you'll have to invoke the `B.app/Contents/MacOS/B` binary directly.

Comment: Running as system("open -a 'B.app/Contents/MacOS/B'"); will fix the problem?